# How can I change the image size of a Plotly saved image?

Tags: python, image, graph, size, plotly

Im trying to figure out how I can change size of the image in my Plotly saved image.. right now the size is small but i would like to change it so that its better to see details.[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to export your figure as your desired image file format, at the resolution you specified for your figure, you can use the `plotly.io.write_image` function.

Example from the link below, the documentation (where fig is your image, and you want a .PNG):

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.write_image(fig, 'images/fig1.png')
```

This also works for .JPEG, .WebP and even vector formats .SVG, .PDF and .EPS. Just replace .PNG with what you need.

https://plot.ly/python/static-image-export/

As further response:
to get the precise size you want, you can change your layout to *include* the following (where fig is your figure):

```
layout = go.Layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=500,
    height=500
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
pio.write_image(fig, 'images/fig1.png')
```

from: https://plot.ly/python/setting-graph-size/
This should let you give the image whatever dimensions you want.

Comment: Thank you! But i have this, this is the result of this function, i would like to change the size of the figure beeing saved to disk, for example, i would like to save the image 50% bigger in size.

Comment: I added some extra information to the answer to help you with this.

Answer (score 10):

You can specify the height and width when saving the file and increase the scale size for better quality.

```
import plotly.io as pio

pio.write_image(fig, file, format=png/jpeg/svg, scale=1, width=1000, height=800)
```

Answer (score 6):

There is even an easier way, imho, to define the width and height of the saved image, which is to just add the values to the parameters width and height in the method write_image, as below:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.write_image(fig, 'yourImage.png', width=1980, height=1080)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this works:

```
dcc.Graph(
id='graph_name',
config={        
    "toImageButtonOptions": {"width": 800, "height": 600, "filename": 'graph_filename'}
})
```